# Scale vector to zero

Tags: vectors

First time poster, so I'll do my best to keep my question clear.

I have two vectors:

$v_1 = (100, 4, 25)$

$v_2 = (0, 2, 3)$

I want to calculate the distance between $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Here's the catch: All $v_2$ dimensions are on a [0, 3] scale, while $v_1$'s dimensions are on arbitrary scales.

How do I scale $v_2$'s dimensions so that the minimum value of a $v_2$ dimension corresponds to 0, and the maximum value of a $v_2$ dimension corresponds to 3?

My objective is to make the distance calculation meaningful based on the **relative** value of the $v_1$ dimensions.

Comment: What does the vector represent?

Comment: Does $=>$ mean "becomes"? Don't use incorrectly a mathematical symbol (when you could write in English properly).

Comment: @smcc The vector is actually a 12-dimensional vector that represents camera specifications. I'm scoring them irrelevant/low/med/high (0/1/2/3).

Comment: @paf Yes, $=>$ means "becomes". I have edited the question. What does $=>$ mean in mathematical terms?

Comment: You cannot subtract the same value from each entry. That would change the direction of the vector. However, you could divide each entry by some number. Normalize means that you want to create a vector of length $1$ having the same direction as your given vector. Here that means dividing everything by $\sqrt{50}$. For sure, each entry will then be less than $3$. Just wondering, where is this question coming from?

Comment: $=>$ (or better $\Rightarrow$) means "implies" : $A\Rightarrow B$ means "if $A$ is true, then $B$ is true”.

Comment: If you mean what I *think* you mean, you will have to specify the range of values for each coordinate, then make a linear map of each of those coordinate ranges onto your normalized range $[0,3]$.

Comment: Divide by magnitude and multiple by 3.

Comment: @paf That's clear, thanks

Comment: @imranfat How do you offset a vector so that it's pointing in the same direction but starts at $(0, 0, 0, ...)$ You're right, I need to scale it, not normalize it. I have amended my question.

Comment: @MPW Yes, that is what I mean. What's the most efficient way to create the linear map?

Comment: @ritwiksinha Does that map 3 to 0?

Comment: @seadragon Oh, I think I see your point now. The problem is then, from which point in space do you count 3 unit in the $x$, 4 units in the $y$ and 5 units in the $z$? If we do not know from where in space your given vector is drawn, it becomes ambiguous in my view...

Comment: @imranfat I think I wasn't clear. The vector is at (3, 4, 5), but I want to scale it so that it is at (0, y , 3), where 3 becomes 0, 5 becomes 3, and 4 becomes what it should become to maintain the direction of the original vector. Am I being more clear?

Comment: @seadragon Yes, it is clearer now, and I have no answer at this point......The given vector is in the first octant (all entries positive), but if you want to have a vector with x component zero, the new vector can never point in the same direction as the given vector as with a zero component you are no longer in the first octant, so I am clueless...

Comment: @imranfat Ah I think I'm the one who has been thinking about this incorrectly. Let me state my problem correctly: My vector actually starts at (1, 2, 3), goes to (3, 4, 5), and I want it to start at (0, 0, 0), point in the same direction, but scale the magnitude such that it fits between [0, 3]. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @seadragon No that is a BIG difference in interpretation. From 1 to 3 means from 0 to 2, from 2 to 4 means from 0 to 2 and from 3 to 5 means from 0 to 2. So if you choose $<2,2,2>$ you have a vector parallel to your given vector.

Comment: @imranfat Ah I think I have been thinking about this incorrectly. Stating my problem again: I have several 12-dimensional arrays of values. I want to compute the distance between those and a chosen vector. However, each vector is using a different scale, so it's not apples to apples. My thinking is that I need to scale the vectors to a common scale [0, 3] where 0 corresponds to the dimension's minimum value and 3 corresponds to the dimension's maximum value, in order to make the distance calculations meaningful. Is that the right approach?

Comment: I sincerely apologize, but I think I am not getting the crux the of the problem anymore. Hopefully someone else could weigh in here....

Comment: @imranfat My apologies for leading us down a rabbit hole. I greatly appreciate your time and attention.

Comment: @seadragon Yes but i think you want something else. I think what you want is set 3 as 0 and 5 as 3 and map all the values in between 3 and 5 accordingly.  Am i correct ?

Comment: @ritwiksinha Yes, precisely! I want to scale 3 to 0, 5 to 3, and set any in-between values accordingly. I confused the problem by injecting the vector stuff, which is a different, but unrelated, step.

Comment: @seadragon That is non uniform translation, which i have no idea how to do. Edit the question and some one will answer it.

Comment: @ritwiksinha I have just edited the question to be much clearer based on my improved understanding of the problem. Hopefully it is meaningful, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**COMMENT:** (This is a comment, not an answer; I'm writing it here because it's more convenient.)

It's very unclear what you want. Can you clarify? Here are some questions/observations on which it would be helpful for you to elaborate.

(1) It sounds like you have several samples of 12-tuples, say $N$ samples
$$S^{(1)}=(s^{(1)}_1,s^{(1)}_2,s^{(1)}_3,\cdots,s^{(1)}_{12})$$
$$S^{(2)}=(s^{(2)}_1,s^{(2)}_2,s^{(2)}_3,\cdots,s^{(2)}_{12})$$
$$\cdots$$
$$S^{(n)}=(s^{(n)}_1,s^{(n)}_2,s^{(n)}_3,\cdots,s^{(n)}_{12})$$
where the superscripts indicate the sample ID and the subscripts distinguish among the 12 components (coordinates) of the tuples. Is this accurate?

(2) Is it true that the possible range of values for each slot may be different? For example, maybe the first coordinate values for all the samples, $s^{(1)}_1, s^{(2)}_1, s^{(3)}_1,\cdots, s^{(12)}_1$, are all in the range $[2,5]$, while (say) the second coordinate values for all the samples, $s^{(1)}_2, s^{(2)}_2, s^{(3)}_2,\cdots, s^{(12)}_2$, are all in the range $[0,1]$.

(3) If the answer to (2) is "yes", then do you want to scale all of the coordinates so that *all* of the scaled coordinates take value in the range $[0,3]$?

**MORE:** If these are correct, then suppose the $k$th coordinate has a range of values $[a_k,b_k]$. You seek a linear map *for that coordinate* $f_k:[a_k,b_k] \to[c,d]$ (here $c=0$ and $d=3$, so the target range is $[0,3]$; I present a more general map, so you can use any $c$ and $d$ you wish). Such a map is just

$$f_k(x) = c + \left(\frac{d-c}{b_k-a_k}\right)(x-a_k)$$
so in the case $c=0$ and $d=3$ this would be
$$f_k(x) = \left(\frac{3}{b_k-a_k}\right)(x-a_k)$$

The transformed sample 12-tuples would be

$$\hat S^{(n)}=(f_1(s^{(n)}_1),f_2(s^{(n)}_2),f_3(s^{(n)}_3),\cdots,f_{12}(s^{(n)}_{12}))$$

But it's not at all clear if this is what you want.

**EVEN MORE:** To see why the linear map $$f(x) = c + \left(\frac{d-c}{b-a}\right)(x-a)$$ maps the interval $[a,b]$ onto the interval $[c,d]$, note that it is the composition of the following maps:

$x\mapsto x-a$ shifts the interval $[a,b]$ to the origin, so the image is $[0,b-a]$.

$x\mapsto \left(\frac{d-c}{b-a}\right)x$ scales the interval $[0,b-a]$ onto the interval $[0,d-c]$.

$x\mapsto x + c$ shifts the interval $[0,d-c]$ onto the interval $[c,d]$.

The composition of these maps gives the desired map $f$, which maps the interval $[a,b]$ linearly onto the interval $[c,d]$.

Comment: Yes, precisely! I want to scale 3 to 0, 5 to 3, and set any in-between values accordingly. I confused the problem by injecting the vector stuff, which is a different, but unrelated, step. – $\color{blue}{\text{seadragon 2 hours ago}}$ $\qquad$

Comment: @MPW Thanks for in-depth comment. I have just edited the question to be much clearer. I'll also answer your questions here. Yes, I will have several samples of the 12-d tuple. Yes, the possible ranges for each dimension can be (vastly) different, for example [1M,42M], or [5,12]. Yes, I would like all of the scaled coordinates to take values in the range [0,3]. The reason is because the vector I want to compare these 12-d tuples to is on a [0,3] scale (please see edited question). I am working through your linear map now. I appreciate this a lot!

Comment: @MPW That works perfectly! Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help. Note how the "magic" linear map works (I added an additional comment at the end of my answer).